# Is there any way to find os name using java?

Tags: java

Is there any way to find os name  using java ?

I have tried below code, but it will returns looks like (Linux , windows..)

```
System.getProperty("os.name")
```

I need to detecting below format

> Linux - "ubuntu, mandriva .. " , windows - "xp,vista ..."

sorry for my English :-( !!!

Any idea ?

Comment: In your example, `os.name` would return `Windows XP` for example.

Comment: @assylias sorry. i am linux user. i dont know windows result. i want to linux os name(ubuntu..)

Comment: i am new in this blog. thanks for sharing link

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically determine operating system in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `System.getProperty()` to get the following properties:

- `os.name`: Operating system name
- `os.arch`: Operating system architecture
- `os.version`: Operating system version

In your case, I believe you're looking for the `os.version` property.  The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) for `System.getProperties()` contain a full list of properties that you can retrieve.

**Edit**

I just tested this in Linux Mint and it appears that the getting the `os.version` property actually returns the kernel version, and not the distro version:

```
Linux
amd64
2.6.38-8-generic
```

After finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334426/find-name-of-linux-distro-from-java), it seems as though there's no reliable way to find which Linux distribution you're running through the Java API.

If you know you're running in Linux, you can instead run one of the following system commands from Java, but you'll have to grep/parse out the distribution:

- `cat /etc/*-release`

Comment: In fact, `uname -a` doesn't include distribution name.  (Or at least on Fedora, it doesn't.)  And you should probably use "/etc/system-release" ... because (again on Fedora, at least) the "/etc/*-release" pattern matches 3 pathnames.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that would get ugly then because on Linux Mint, the distribution name is stored in /etc/lsb-release.  I remember reading a while back to include the wildcard because the file in which the distro version is stored in is not consistent across distributions. Maybe it would be worth piping the output to `grep DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION`?  Either way, I'll edit my answer -- thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Greping "/etc/*-release" for DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION doesn't work on Fedora.  The file(s) all consist of just "Fedora release 16 (Verne)".

Answer (score 5):

This might help you:

```
System.out.println("\nName of the OS: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
System.out.println("Version of the OS: " + System.getProperty("os.version"));
System.out.println("Architecture of the OS: " + System.getProperty("os.arch"));
```

EDIT:This is what it returns under Windows:

```
Name of the OS: Windows XP
Version of the OS: 5.1
Architecture of the OS: x86
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few system properties that you can query.  Have a look a [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for details.  A combination of some or all of these 3 should help you:

```
System.getProperty("os.arch")
System.getProperty("os.name")
System.getProperty("os.version")
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29

property: 'os.name'